# convering the dates into weeks (In a month the weeks should not be more than 4) Tried with weeknum, weekdays but weeks coming more than 5

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I am looking for a formula in excel

Comment: and why should there only be 4?  If the weeks start with the 1st then anything over 28 will be in the 5th week.

Comment: Hi Scott, It is one of the requirements for the project. Weeks should be strictly 4 in month

Comment: That is mathematically impossible, unless the other weeks have more than 7 days.  If week 4 can have 7-10 days then it is possible.

Comment: 1 to 7 week 1,    8 to 14 week 2,    15 to 21 week 3,    22 to 30/31 week4.

Comment: Then use `=MIN(INT(Day(A2)-1)/7)+1,4)`  where `A2` is your actual date.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I will try this and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Scott's formula contained a subtraction that wasn't needed, but I think this file has what you want.

```
=MIN(INT(DAY(A17)/7)+1,4)
```

You can see [results here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g6s0WYD5rJNiun_Ccg?e=a5jBHP).

[image]

Comment: it is needed or 7th will be in week 2.  And as your data shows, the 21st should be week 3 and yours returns week 4

Comment: But my `)` were off: `=MIN(INT((Day(A2)-1)/7)+1,4)`